# Expose current logged in user globally in Angular and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm looking for a clear and elegant way to have the current logged in user exposed everywhere in my app because I have a navigation partial view that contains the user information as well as a logout button but I haven't been able to accomplish that.

My starting point is this sample app https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed and
I just added an AppCtrl where I can expose the current logged in user. I have tried adding the user provider but that doesn't work either.

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope','simpleLogin', 'fbutil', '$location', function($scope, $rootScope, simpleLogin, fbutil, $location) {
  $scope.user = simpleLogin.getUser();
  $scope.logout = function() {
    var profile = fbutil.syncObject(['users', simpleLogin.getUser().uid]);
    profile.$destroy();
    simpleLogin.logout();
    $location.path('/login');
  };
}])
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

Your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `resolve` parameter - this exists both in [`$routerProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) and [`$stateProvide`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve). `resolve` resolves the objects (including resolving a promise) and then these objects are available to your controllers. In this case, you "resolve" your loggedInUser variable (by doing whatever you need to do via your authentication service.

```
$routeProvider
   .when("/someSecuredContent", {
     templateUrl: 'someSecuredContent.html',
     controller: 'SecuredController',
     resolve: {
        loggedInUser: function(MyAuth){
           return MyAuth.loggedIn(); // MyAuth.loggedIn() should return a $q promise
        }
     }
});
```

Then in the controller, `loggedInUser` will be injected.

Here's a [site](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) with more examples.

Comment: This is also [covered in the AngularFire guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes) with some working examples for Firebase auth.

Answer (score 0):

After using multiple methods for exposing the current logged in user globally, I think it is best described in this [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/learn-to-build-realtime-webapps/), specifically in the "Accessing the current user throughout the application" section. Also the tutorial is awesome and I think they have got the architecture right for this type of application.