# Maintaining client side page state on page refresh in angular.js applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, single-page-application

I am  building an Single Page app using angular.js and I am facing this issue for which I am not able to find the right answer.

When we do a full page refresh in an angular app, how should we check if the user still has a valid session ?? State Provider or UI router merely routes the url to the requested page, but what if the session of the user has expired ?

One thing that comes to my mind is to use a service and store a Boolean value there once the user logs in and on every page refresh or state change, we check this Boolean and redirect the user to login page,  if this value is false. But, if we do a refresh, this Boolean value is reset.

Thought of storing this key value in a cookie or  html local storage, but how safe are these values getting stored here. Some one can reset the value of this Boolean to gain access to a page.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a client-side app secure you will need to involve a server of some sort. Storing values in cookies or local storage will not do any good as these can be manipulated by a user (as can everything else on the browser).

Not sure what options you have available to you but I would recommend looking into Nodejs/Expressjs/Passportjs - this is a pretty awesome combo and very good support here on SO.

Once you make progress in this area you will then be in a position to ask a more focused question.

Comment: We have jboss server at the back end, which send me valid jsessionId's. This works well for XHR requests, but in angular state or route changes, should I make a call to the backend with my jession to check if the user has a valid session ? to navigate to this new page ?

Comment: You should check on every request that they have a valid session.

Comment: Yup, it boils down to checking the session on every request.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're conflating a few concepts here.

**One** - is the user authentication to the server. It must be the server, otherwise the concept of a user session in a client-side-only app is useless. This is facilitated (typically) by an authentication cookie. The cookie is a security token given to the user and signed by something secret on the server. The cookie contains things like login name and expiration. The cookie is *validated by the server* on every request the browser makes.

**Two** - is the nice user experience maintained in the client-side app. What I mean by that, is that if you didn't check whether the cookie has expired, your ajax calls to the server would (and should) fail with HTTP 401 - Unauthorized. You likely would want to prevent that, and have your app preemptively redirect to a login page, or if applicable, request to refresh the security token.

So what does all of that mean?

1. Enforce authentication on the server
2. Create a loginService that checks session expiration from a cookie, or whatever else you use fo your user authentication.
3. Use `resolve` parameter of [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) or [$stateProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) to have the loginInfo available to controllers. Here's [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049927/expose-current-logged-in-user-globally-in-angular-and-firebase/26051645#26051645) on SO to a question you might find useful.

Comment: Your answer summarizes very nicely. Thanks !!